# Protractor+Typescript : Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, gulp-protractor

How can we configure the selenium grid in protractor?

Do we need to create hub and node like how we do with selenium?

How can we run the "webdriver-manager" as hub/node?

Thanks

Harsh

Comment: Is my understanding correct? Do you want to execute your tests on different browsers which are installed in different remote machines?

Comment: @Sudharsan Selvaraj.. yes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below configuration,

```
multiCapabilities: [
 {
   browserName: 'chrome',
   seleniumAddress : "http://remotemachine1:4444/wd/hub"
 },
 {
   browserName: 'firefox',
   seleniumAddress : "http://remotemachine2:4444/wd/hub"
 }
].
```

Before executing the test you need to start the selenium server using `webdriver-manger start` on both the remote machines.